# How can I find the current full path of a json node using Jackson?

Tags: json, jackson

I have a JsonParser defined in the class.  I will be traversing through it. But when I do that, I will need to get the full path of the current node I am in.  What is the best way to extract the full path without affecting the performance.  Is there an API in Jackson that already does that?

Answer (score 1):

You can get context information with `JsonParser.getParsingContext()`. Or, if you want location relative to input source (line, column), you can use `JsonParser.getLocation()`.